# print a mysql query in laravel5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have the following code on my controller for update the record

```
    $inforequest = Info::find($id);
    $inforequest->infoname = $inforequest->infoname;
    $inforequest->infotitle = $inforequest->infotitle;
    $inforequest->infotag = $inforequest->infotag;
    $inforequest->infogroup = $inforequest->infogroup;
    $last_query = $inforequest->save();
    return redirect('auth/getallinfo');
```

But it's not updating the data as well as not given any error

How can i print the mysql query???

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toSql()` method.

```
 $inforequest = Info::find($id)->toSql();
 dd($inforequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

To investigate on my queries, i placed in the **boot()** function in **AppServiceProvider** a listenere for the DB:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        [...]
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            echo '<br>_____________<br>';
            var_dump($query->sql);
            var_dump(($query->time/1000)." sec");
            echo '<br>-------------<br>';
        });
    }
}
```

I used to print out both the query and the time (converted in seconds) of the query.
You can also var_dump the whole $query.